discrepancy between directory trees Google drive and Google Colab
Please note both trees and the missing direcctories, please note Drive is already mounted. The code can not find these directories !! Your help is appreciated.
input_dir = 'drive/MyDrive/data/240/test/water/water2'  # Change to your input directory
output_dir = 'drive/MyDrive/data/240/test/water1'  # Change to your output directory
resize_images_in_directory(input_dir, output_dir, new_size=(240, 240))

Input directory not found: drive/MyDrive/data/240/test/water/water2

